# Is this normal behavior for std::bitset::operator^= and std::bitset::count ? If so, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, bitset

As documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_logic), `std::bitset::operator^=` returns `*this`. From that and from the "usual" interpretation of operators such as `+=, |=, *=` one could reasonably assume that given `std::bitset` instances (of the same size) `a` and `b`, the expression `(a^=b).count()` will store the result of a bitwise `XOR` operation in `a`, and that `count()` would return the number of bits in `a` that are set to `true`. However, as the following minimal example demonstrates, something unexpected happens:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    constexpr unsigned int N=6; 
    std::bitset<N> a; 
    std::bitset<N> b; 

    a.flip();//111111
    b[0]=1;
    b[4]=1;//b is now 010001 (assuming least significan bit on the right end of the string)

    std::cout<<"a=="<<a.to_string()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"b=="<<b.to_string()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"(a xor b) to string=="<<(a^=b).to_string()<<std::endl;

    //Here is the unexpected part!
    std::cout<<"(a xor b) count=="<<(a^=b).count()<<std::endl;
    //Note that the following lines would produce the correct result
    //a^=b;
    //std::cout<<a.count()<<std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
a==111111
b==010001
(a xor b) to string==101110       
(a xor b) count==6                //this is wrong!!!!! It should be 4...
```

A quick look at the implementation of `std::bitset` (see [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/bitset)) seems to indicate that the reference that is returned is indeed a reference to the lhs object (`a` in my example). So... Why is this happening?

Comment: Use `(a^b).count()`, not `(a^=b).count()`. You are *assigning* `a`, and toggling the bit states back and forth.

Comment: `(a^=b)` is being evaluated twice.

Comment: The thing is your comment is wrong. Replacing the "broken" line with the alternative produces the same output. Unless you meant to keep both the "broken" line *and* the alternative.

Comment: @RichardCritten Ahhhh okay right... Thank you... How silly of me.

Comment: in C++, as a rule of thumb, if you use the character `=` then the description of what you're doing will involve the word "equal".  in the case of `a^=b` it's "a equals a^b" in the case of `a==b` it's "does a equal b" etc  There are many operators that have an =

Comment: `^` is `xor`, `^=` is `xor` *assignment*. You don't want to modify `a`, you just want the result of `a xor b`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the bitset. Consider this code:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
std::cout << std::to_string(a *= b) << std::endl; // Prints 6.
std::cout << std::to_string(a *= b) << std::endl; // Prints 18.
```

You are using an assignment operator, so your variable/bitset changes **every** time. In your case, the second evaluation yields `((a ^ b) ^ b)`, which is of course the original `a` (which did have 6 bits set).